# Is there a unit testing framework for Rascal?

Tags: rascal

I did not see one in the standard library documentation. A Google search gives as the top hit "Rascal Unit travel pet sterilization and wellness clinic princing [sic] information."

Comment: the current google search returns a link to this question :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, it turns out that tests are built into Rascal. Simply add the modifier "test" to a boolean function to make it a test.  The command ":test" will run all the tests in scope. If the test takes parameters, Rascal will do some randomized testing for you.